# How can I create a virtual subnet that spans multiple servers?

Tags: centos, networking, subnets

I have some CentOS 7 servers hosting VMs.  The VMs are connected to a network bridge on their respective hosts that allows them to communicate with each other and with the host (via a dummy adapter on the host).  The hosts also each have a physical adapter which allows external communication.  **The bridges must not be connected to the physical adapters.**

This diagram should make the current layout clear.  Subnet A connects the hosts to each other.  Subnet B exists entirely within host 1.  Subnet C exists entirely within host 2.  **The VMs must not have addresses on subnet A.**

[image: Current network layout]

I'd like to combine the two bridges into a single virtual subnet so all the VMs share the same address space and broadcast domain.  Is there a way to do this?  Here's the goal:

[image: Desired network layout]

The VMs have CloudStack "public" IP addresses, which need to belong to their respective subnets. The VMs must not be in the same address space as subnet A. CloudStack public IP ranges are defined at the zone level, so the VMs would have to be all on the same subnet to get them into the same zone, let alone the same pod. The hosts can route traffic between the subnets. I can't add more subnet A addresses to the hosts, and I also can't use NAT on the hosts. I'm also unable to set up VLANs in subnet A. For most purposes, subnet A is outside the scope of what I can control.

Comment: Host 1 provides a VPN (e.g. `openvpn`), Host 2 connects to it (via `A` obviously). All VMs NAT to the VPN only. Don't ask me how to implement it, but that should be the way to go. However this makes Host1 and Host2 appear on the networks for the VMs.

Comment: "Must not be connected", yet the data must be transported over Subnet A. (Subnet is not the right word here, I guess. Do you mean broadcast domain? Being precise what the thing is you mean is a bit crucial here.) What is it **exactly** that must not happen?

Comment: "_I'd like to combine the two bridges into a single virtual subnet_" have you considered joining the two bridges using a VLAN on the physical network?

Comment: @roaima that works within one broadcast domain, which is why I asked for specifics... mrog, what's the virtualizer you're using? The "larger players" already come with solution for this kind of problem.

Comment: Multiple VMware servers with a distributed switch? Yes good point, @MarcusMüller

Comment: @MarcusMüller What I mean by "must not be connected" is that they must not be directly connected.  So, the bridge that exists on the host must not be connected to the host's physical adapter.  The hosts can route traffic between the subnets.  But the VMs must not be in the same address space as subnet A.  I'm also unable to set up VLANs in subnet A.  For most purposes, subnet A is outside the scope of what I can control.

Comment: @MarcusMüller The virtualizer is KVM controlled by CloudStack.  One goal is to get all the VMs into the same CloudStack pod.

Comment: The VMs have CloudStack "public" IP addresses, which need to belong to their respective subnets.  CloudStack public IP ranges are defined at the zone level, so the VMs would have to be all on the same subnet to get them into the same zone, let alone the same pod.  And, before you ask, no I can't add more subnet A addresses to the hosts.  I also can't use NAT on the hosts.

Comment: I feel like there should be a way to do this using Open vSwitch, but I haven't figured out how.

Comment: I found a solution using L2TP, but it only works with exactly 2 hosts.  I'm unable to add a second L2TP tunnel to a host.  Is there a version of mGRE (or something similar) for Linux?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to solve this by creating an overlay network using vxlan.  I added a vxlan adapter to each host, and connected the adapters to the bridges on the hosts.  One of the hosts serves as a router to connect the vxlan subnet to the rest of the network.